# Passing through Segues, Determining what view the user is on and NavigationController buttons not appearing

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, segue

Sorry for the long and possibly confusing question. In this I have 2 main problems with my code, those being: 1- When I embed my viewControllers in a UINavigationController and add a bar button item, nothing appears, yet it appears when I add it to the pageViewController. Secondly, I am wondering if there is a way to do this differently and use one button on the pageView (which appears on all viewcontrollers in it) and just determine what the user was looking at when they pressed the button and are taken to another viewcontroller.

I am trying to build a page-based application, and I have set up the application with 7 view controllers (One for each day of the week). I then have an AddViewController, where users can add data to a certain day. I was wondering if there is a way to only use 1 addView linked to the NavBar on the PageViewController, as when I embed all other viewControllers and add a bar button, it does not show up.

With the pageViewController being embedded, this is what it looks like with a bar button on it.

[image: PageViewController Bar Button]

This then leads to:

[image: Back]

Which works well, however I am wanting to pass data to various arrays (one for each viewController), and I want to know which ViewController the user wishes to add to (based off what day they were on). Is there a way to determine this and then unwind to the viewController and append the right data to the right array or should I have one addView per dayViewController? If that is the case, I am coming across the issue whereby the bar button items do not appear on the viewControllers when they are embedded in a navigationController. It looks like this:

StoryBoard: (Example: MondayViewController)

[image: Storyboard]

The outcome is a missing barButton: (Keep in mind I changed the tint Colour to white so it would be visible)

[image]

I was wondering if anyone has the answer to either of my problems, and once again, thanks for taking the time to look at this array of questions in one problem.

Any suggestions are welcome !

Rowan,

Comment: Not an answer but....  Wouldn't it be simpler to have one view controller that represents any day of the week and only reload new data when the day changes?  Multiple controllers usually imply different visible structure, not just content.  As for "pass data to various arrays", that works better by having one data model object that manages application state and serves as a reference for the controllers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have (like you said) one view controller that represents each day of the week (7), and the data is in the same class, however just for ease, I have different arrays within that class which are the source of the data for the view, however I do like the idea of one data model. With regards to reloading the collectionView, my intentions are only to reload it after the unwind segue has been performed

Comment: Actually, I was suggesting one view controller to handle all seven days rather than one each.  (i.e. One controller could represent any day if the structure stays the same and only the content changes.)  It would mean that you didn't really need pages, which would probably simplify the other things you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

Create an `UINavigationViewController` and then embed an `UIPageViewController` in it.

In the data source for the `UIPageViewController` implement these two methods:

```
- pageViewController:viewControllerBeforeViewController:
- pageViewController:viewControllerAfterViewController:
```

Here you will return the correct instance of your `DayViewController` for each position (or `nil` if you are on the first/last page). Your data model would also be set here.

Add your "Add" bar button to the navigation bar of the `UIPageViewController` and let it push your `AddViewController`. When pushing the `AddViewController` provide to it the info on which day is currently visible. You will probably need to keep track of this your self. Use the `- pageViewController:didFinishAnimating:previousViewControllers:transitionCompleted:` method of the `UIPageViewController` delegate.